# Why does my bcrypt password hash always start with $2y$05$

Tags: php, bcrypt

I'm creating a password hash using a salt and a cost of 5 and every time the hash Is created it starts with '$2y$05$' is there any reason for this?

Comment: `$` is the field separator, `2y` identifies bcrypt as the hashing method, and `05` means 2^5 iterations.

Comment: Nice, thanks very much. 2y indicates that bcrypt is the hashing method are there 1y, 3y?

Comment: There are [many](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is a field seperator.
`2y` is a version field, this version number indicates that a [significant security flaw](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12132/could-the-bcrypt-ruby-binding-be-vulnerable) has been fixed. There have been others.
`05` indicates the cost (`2^5` in your case) that has been put into creating the hash.